# Identity Server with Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, identityserver4

I would like to use Identity Server to authenticate an application against Azure Active Directory. Our company's infrastructure is managed by a contractor.  What piece of information do I need to get from them in order for Identity Server to authenticate?  Is it an Url that I need?  Is it the client that looks like a Guid?  That contractor won't give me the information I need unless I'm asking the right question.  Also is there an example that's already doing this?

Comment: azure AD should be usable with a common oAuth approach

Comment: any specific technology such as .net or php?